# Flot Charts using SQL Server db with multiple y axis

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, flot

This is my first post, apologies if I've asked a question a number of people have already done so. I don't see the answer I need in other posts.

I'm using Flot Charts and have a SQL Server db, I've got a php file that will connect to the db and return all the values within the sql in an array.

```
<?php

$server =  "XXXX";
$database = "XXXX";
$user = "ReportsUser";
$pwd = "ReportsUser";
$cnn = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client     10.0};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $pwd);

if(!$cnn)
{
  echo "error in connecting";
}

$sql = odbc_exec($cnn, "
            SELECT Months
        ,Referrals
            ,ProjectedVol
        FROM mis.ReferralsBudgetvsActual
        WHERE Months <= MONTH(GETDATE())
    ");

while($result = odbc_fetch_array($sql))
{
   $allreferrals[] = array($result['Months'],$result['Referrals'],$result['ProjectedVol']);
}
echo json_encode(($allreferrals), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
exit;

?>
```

This works well and produces the array as below

`[[1,5981,7465],[2,5473,6962],[3,4974,7391],[4,5731,6985],[5,5891,7080],[6,5168,7136],[7,5551,7543],[8,4427,7242],[9,4617,7204],[10,4807,7642]]`

Now, when it all comes together in the jquery file, this is where I end up getting stuck. I don't see where it pulls any other columns back apart from the first data column, how can this be done?

```
// document ready function
$(document).ready(function() {  

        var chartColours = ['#88bbc8', '#ed7a53', '#9FC569', '#bbdce3', '#9a3b1b', '#5a8022', '#2c7282'];

        // function for refreshing shiftstats chart  
        make_chart();
        function make_chart() {

            $.ajax({
                cache: 'false',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "test.php",
                success: function(data) {

                var d1 = data;
                var d2 = data;                    

                //define placeholder class
                var placeholder = $(".shifts-chart");
                //graph options
                var options = {
                        grid: {
                            show: true,
                            aboveData: true,
                            color: "#3f3f3f" ,
                            labelMargin: 5,
                            axisMargin: 0, 
                            borderWidth: 0,
                            borderColor:null,
                            minBorderMargin: 5 ,
                            clickable: true, 
                            hoverable: true,
                            autoHighlight: true,
                            mouseActiveRadius: 20
                        },
                        series: {
                            grow: {
                                active: false,
                                stepMode: "linear",
                                steps: 50,
                                stepDelay: true
                            },
                            lines: {
                                show: true,
                                fill: false,
                                lineWidth: 4,
                                steps: false
                                },
                            points: {
                                show:true,
                                radius: 5,
                                symbol: "circle",
                                fill: true,
                                borderColor: "#fff"
                            }
                        },
                        legend: { 
                            position: "ne", 
                            margin: [0,-25], 
                            noColumns: 0,
                            labelBoxBorderColor: null,
                            labelFormatter: function(label, series) {
                                // just add some space to labes
                                return label+'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                             }
                        },
                        yaxis: { min: 0 },
                        xaxis: {ticks:11, tickDecimals: 0},
                        colors: chartColours,
                        shadowSize:1,
                        tooltip: true, //activate tooltip
                        tooltipOpts: {
                            content: "%s : %y.0",
                            shifts: {
                                x: -30,
                                y: -50
                            }
                        }
                    };   
                    $.plot(placeholder,
                        [{
                            label: "Referrals", 
                            data: d1,
                            lines: {fillColor: "#f2f7f9"},
                            points: {fillColor: "#88bbc8"}
                        },
                        {
                            label: "ProjectedVol", 
                            data: d2,
                            lines: {fillColor: "#f2f7f9"},
                            points: {fillColor: "#88bbc8"}
                        } 
                        ], options);                                                               
                    } 
                });
            }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what this sentance means: ***I don't see where it pulls any other columns back apart from the first data column, how can this be done?***  Your JSON returns a single series of data which you duplicate into `d1` and `d2`.

Comment: That's the bit I'm struggling with, I can see why/how d1 pulls from data but as the array fed into the JSON includes all columns, how do I make the JSON recognize the second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change your php array creation to properly format the data into two series:

```
$d1 = array();
$d2 = array();

while($result = odbc_fetch_array($sql))
{
   array_push($d1, array($result['Months'], $result['Referrals']));
   array_push($d2, array($result['Months'], $result['ProjectedVol']));
}

$allreferrals = array($d1, $d2);
echo json_encode(($allreferrals), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

This should return it as an array of arrays:

```
[
  [[1,5981],[2,5473],[3,4974],[4,5731],[5,5891],[6,5168],[7,5551],[8,4427],[9,4617,7204],[10,4807]],
  [[1,7465],[2,6962],[3,7391],[4,6985],[5,7080],[6,7136],[7,7543],[8,7242],[9,7204],[10,7642]] 
]
```

(Hopefully I have the syntax correct, I'm not a fan of php)

**Update from comment**

If you are returning a slew of series, you might be better returning an associative array from PHP:

```
$allreferrals = array('ref' => array(), 'projVol'=> array());

while($result = odbc_fetch_array($sql))
{
   array_push($allreferrals['ref'], array($result['Months'], $result['Referrals']));
   array_push($allreferrals['projVol'], array($result['Months'], $result['ProjectedVol']));
}

echo json_encode(($allreferrals), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Then back in the javascript:

```
$.plot(placeholder,
    [{
        label: "Referrals", 
        data: data["ref"]
      },
      {
         label: "ProjectedVol", 
         data: data["projVol"]
      }], 
 options);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, when applying this to what I have then it returns the array just like how you have shown above. From this how would the JSON understand there is a second line in the array? Would it need to be var d1 = data; again along with var d2 = data;

Comment: @Jez `d1 = data[0]` and `d2 = data[1]`

Comment: Superb and then if I have more, do I add the lines in the array and change the var dX = data[X] etc?

Comment: @Jez, essentially yes.  At some point though, it would be better to return a little more robust data structure from the php.  See my edits above...

Comment: thank for this. I've applied to what I've done and yes I can see how it runs a little better and definately more robust when using bigger data sets... Now when I look at doing the other style of charts, Bar Charts, Pie Charts etc, would this all apply as looking at the example they pull data through differently?